# "Custom Scripts" setting inside our tenant, How it works exactly

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, modern-experience, script

I spent many days reading about how "Custom scripts" work for sharepoint online, but i can not fully understand it. for example we have this case.

1. inside SP admin center >> Settings >> we have custom scripts disabled as follow:-

[image]

2. now using the office 365 admin (who is also a sharepoint admin), i created 2 sites (modern communication site + classic team site).
3. so now i got these "custom script" setting for the site collections:-

   - our build-in root site collection (which is a classic team site)--> custom scripts is **Disabled**.
   - the modern site collection --> custom scripts is **Disabled**.
   - the classic team site which i created --> custom scripts is **Enabled**!!

so i have the following questions:-

1. since we have prevent custom scripts inside the "SharePoint admin center", then how custom script was enabled inside the classic team site i have created?
2. if we allow custom scripts from the "SharePoint admin center", then i assume this will affect future site collections, but will it also affect all our current 3 site collections?
3. if i want to enable custom scripts for our modern communication site collection ONLY. so can i do so? or as a first step i will need to enable custom scripts from "SharePoint admin center" ?
4. if i want to add a script to a classic page. can i Temporary enable custom script on the intended site >> add the custom script >> disable custom script inside the site collection? will the script keep working as-is even if we disable custom script on the site?
5. final question inside the "SharePoint admin center" >> "Custom Script", they use the word "Prevent users" & "Allow users".. so what do users represent? does it cover office 365 & sharepoint admins? or users refer to non-admin users?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable / disable Custom Scripts at the [Tenant Level](http://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2018/10/28/enable-custom-script-on-modern-sharepoint-sites-using-powershell/#step1) and at The [Site level](http://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2018/10/28/enable-custom-script-on-modern-sharepoint-sites-using-powershell/#step2).

Please Read the following posts carefully, most of your questions will be answered:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script
- http://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2018/10/28/enable-custom-script-on-modern-sharepoint-sites-using-powershell/

Both pages have a matrix of the effects of this setting.  Also, the second link talks about why you should not enable Custom Scripts on modern sites.

**Question #1:**

As per Link #1 above, wait 24 hours.  It will be overridden.

**Question #2:**

As per documentation in Link #1, it will override the settings on the current sites until you run this command:

```
Set-SPOsite <SiteURL> -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

**Question #3:**

See Link #2 above.

**Question #4:**

As per link #1 above:  If you change this setting for a user's OneDrive or a classic team site, it will be overridden by the Custom Script setting in the admin center within 24 hours.

**Question #5:**

"Users" all users in SharePoint.  If you allow custom scripts at a tenant or site level, any one with the "Add and Customize Pages" permission level or higher will be able to add custom scripts to a site that they have that permission level (or higher).

Comment: ok thanks for the links, but i actually read them before multiple times. Now since you mentioned that after 24 hours the admin settings will override the settings inside the site collection, so can i conclude that at the end all site collections (modern, classic, root, personal site & self-service site) will have the same custom scripts settings,, as per the sharepoint admin center, and defining custom scripting settings at the site collection level `Set-SPOsite <SiteURL> -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0` will not be permanent change?? or this is not the case?

Comment: No, the way I read it is that lets say you dont want custom scripts on any site collection except 1, you would do the following: Set the desired value at the tenant level and run the  Set-SPOsite <SiteURL> -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0  Powershell on the site you want the exception to apply to.  my experience has been that the only way to un-set this property would be via powershell such as this:   Set-SPOsite <SiteURL> -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 1

Comment: How much experience do you have with SharePoint online?  3 site collections sounds like a test farm.  Do you currently have an on-prem implementation?

Comment: i did not say we only have 3 site collections, we have many site collections and some of them were created by end users, i have the 3 site collections as an example about managing custom scripts...

Comment: second question, u r saying if we enable custom scripting at the tenant level and we disabled it on certain site collections, then the tenant level will not override the site collection level? if the answer is yes, then when the overriden happens?

Comment: I meant no disrespect.  Second Question: The override happens when you change the tenant level setting from one value to another and there are sites whose Custom Scripts setting differ from those set at the tenant level.  Those sites would be affected by the change at the tenant level.

Comment: i am not sure if your second point is correct.. because on this link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script the docs mentioned the following `If you change this setting for a user's OneDrive or a classic team site, it will be overridden by the Custom Script setting in the admin center within 24 hours.` so it says if you chnage the setting for a site collection, it will be overridden by the admin center setting... so it did NOT say that the overridden will ONLY happen when u chnage the setting from the admin center!!!

Comment: If you are correct then the only time you could have a site that had custom script enabled and all others with custom script disabled would be if you set the tenant level setting to permit custom scripts and then disable custom script via power shell for ALL other sites.  That doesn’t really make sense because the documentation goes into detail about permissions and security implication of permitting custom scripts.  If the tenant setting setting is set to enable custom scripts then all self-service sites and/or personal sites would default to enable custom scripts.

Comment: and that why i asked this question,, as it is not clear how the "custom scripts" exactly work in sharepoint online!!! the documentations are not clear and have a lot of missing scenarios...

Comment: also how would you understand this sentence `If you change this setting for a user's OneDrive or a classic team site, it will be overridden by the Custom Script setting in the admin center within 24 hours.` inside the official MS documentation https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88421/discussion-between-a-k-a-fritz-and-sharepoint-testdev).